Torah study vs armed defense
The Midrash tells us that only Torah study protects the Jews:

Rabbi Yehudah HaNasi sent Rabbi Assi and Rabbi Ammi on a mission to organize religious education in the cities of the Land of Israel. They came to a city and said to the people, “Bring us the guardians of the city.” The people then fetched the captain of the guard and the magistrate. The rabbis exclaimed, “You call these the guardians of the city! They are its destroyers!”  [By that they meant:  If you rely only on armed guards and judges, you will be lulled into a false sense of security, and the city will certainly be destroyed.]  The people then asked, “Who, then, are the “guardians of the city”“?  The rabbis answered: They are the teachers of Torah and Mishnah.  It says in the Book of Joshua:
You will study Torah day and night. [Joshua 1:8]" [Lamentations Rabbah, Prologue II]

Today, this argument is being loudly repeated at high levels in the State of Israel, specifically negating the role of the Israeli Defense Forces in protecting the people against the savagery of surrounding Arabs.  This angers many who respond, "Where was Torah study protection on October 7th?"
And Chazal does say, in many places:

If someone comes to kill you, rise early and kill him first. [Berakhot 58a and 62b; Yoma 85b; Sanhedrin 72a; Zohar, Toldot 4:26; Midrash Tanchuma Buber, Pinchas 3:1, 4:1.]

It's tempting to conclude that you need a good dose of both Torah study and armed defense.  Is this issue systematically discussed in our Sources?

Downvoter, answer my question instead.

I didn't downvote, but I'd imagine you should be expecting controversy when you bring up probably the single most controversial and painful issue in Israel right now. Not saying you shoudn't, but if you want to take this seriously, overlook the downvotes. Chag samayach Dr!

@RabbiKaii --  Gam lekha.  I don't mind explained downvotes, but unexplained downvotes should be grounds for expulsion, this being a teaching forum.

This already seems like a good analysis of the obvious. Torah study is what makes all over defenses successful. As for where was the Torah study on October 7th? Probably in the yeshivas and mate midrashim. The solution for defense doesn't mean we can understand all outcomes or necessarily prevent all violence being that we are still in a state of galus

Rashi says that Yaakov Avinu prepared for war and prayed

"...if you rely only on armed guards..." You need both
